# Intermittent JDBC error two-task conversion routine

Tags: oracle, jdbc, groovy

I am intermittently getting the following jdbc error with my oracle db (in remote linux machine)

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-03120: two-task conversion routine: integer overflow
```

The query that mostly breaks(not the only one!) looks like this, note that I am using Groovy Sql

```
String insertScript =
"""
INSERT INTO data_table (invoke_id , trans_type , trans_from ,  
trans_to , serv_type ,msg_type , man_id , recip_id ,  
trx_id , part_id , msg_orig_time , create_time ,  
action_code , num_ranges , use_trx_id, due_date,owner,route,lsa, 
cl_id,hl_id,requ_type,lnp_type,use_invoke_id) 
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
"""

def params = [invokeId,transType,transFrom,transTo,servType,msgType,man,recip,portId,owner,
now,now,"W",1,trxId,dueDate,owner," ", "LSA","CCH"," ","Basic","lspp",invokeId]

sql.execute insertScript, params
```

What I do not understand is why my queries work some time and not other times. Generally it will happen during the first run and only rarely appear in subsequent runs.

**[UPDATE]** I am getting this error sometimes on application startup also, when spring tries to load its context. I am using spring and dbcp for the connection pooling.

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Error preloading the connection pool
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1238)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:113)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
... 46 more
```

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-03120: two-task conversion routine: integer overflow

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:131)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:204)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:406)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.receiveOauth(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:799)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:368)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:508)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:203)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:33)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:510)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:294)
at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.addObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1059)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1235)
... 49 more
```

Comment: How does your query look like? The 'internet's opinion' is that it's most likely a bug in the user application.

Comment: @home I have updated my q with the db query I am using.

Comment: Did you try to execute the statement using an interactive session, e.g. SQL Plus?

Comment: It works fine. In fact most of the time, this query executes fine. Its only sometimes that i get the said error.

Comment: I fear I can't provide any help, seems like a configuration problem... maybe you should transfer it to serverfault.com.

Comment: It's not that 'only sometimes' you have incorrect or invalid data in the parameters is it?

Comment: @tim_yates Nice line of thought. I have 2 big decimals which cant be wrong cause I get them from a select from database. I have one constant int which is set to 1. All the other params are strings(again constant values since this is used for testing) and 2-3 date values. Can the date values be culprit? I convert them to java.sql.Timestamp before adding to params.

Comment: @Abe If you surround the `execute` with `try/catch` blocks, can you catch the error, print out the parameters, and then re-throw the original exception?  That way, you might be able to see if there is a common cause to the error

Comment: @tim_yates I did. This is the output-> [133121, GUI, GUI, NPL, MOBILE, 8004, abcd, test, 133036, abcd, 2011-09-30 04:34:00.406, 2011-09-30 04:34:00.406, W, 1, 133036, null, abcd, , LSA, CCH, , Basic, lspp, 133121]

Comment: @tim_yates Hi tim, I have added a stack trace of this issue. Looks like this has nothing to do with queries as it now happened on application load itself.